# export graphs in excel with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, axlsx

I am using axlsx gem in my application to export data to excel sheet. On other hand I am using [quickchart]api to show graph on frontend. Is there anyway to use quickchart api in .xlsx template or any other gem that allow me to draw graphs in .xlsx templates so I could export the data with graph. Simple is that I want to export graphs on excel file in my rails application. Please help.

Comment: You can do this with `axlsx` using Excel's native chart features. [Examples Can be found Here](https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx/tree/master/examples)

Comment: @engineersmnky thank you soo much. I missed this important information. Hope it will fix the problem.